# bare react native app with expo packages, but I don't want an expo console

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, node-modules

I have a bare react native app.
However, I need the following packages from expo:

```
"expo-file-system": "~15.4.3",
"expo-image-manipulator": "^11.3.0",
"expo-image-picker": "^14.3.2",
```

If I follow this tutorial: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/
(or simply `npx install-expo-modules@latest`)

When I run `npx run-ios` I get my iphone emulator but the node console terminal doesn't show up anymore.

Now I have this (node) terminal:

```
Node found at: /opt/homebrew/bin/node
Starting project at /Users/react_frontend
warning:  Obfuscation SKIPPED [Not a *bundle* command]
Starting Metro Bundler
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄▀▀▄▄▀▀█▄█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ ███▄█  ▀▀▄█ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ ██▄▀▄▀███▀█ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ █ ▀▄▀ █ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█ ▄▀▄▄▀▄█▀ ▄▄▀▀█ ██▄▀▀▀▀▀▄█
█ ▄▄   ▄▀▀██ ▄▄█ █▀  █▄ ▄ █
█▄████▄▄█ ▄▄ █▄ ██
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ██ █▄▀█▀▀ █▄█ ▄█▀ █
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀▀▀█▄█ ▄▄▄█  █   █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄███▄▄█▄▄▄██▄██▄█

› Metro waiting on http://localhost:8081
› Scan the QR code above to open the project in a development build. Learn more:
https://expo.fyi/start

› Using development build
› Press s │ switch to Expo Go

› Press a │ open Android
› Press i │ open iOS simulator
› Press w │ open web

› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› Press o │ open project code in your editor

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
warning: Watchman `watch-project` returned a warning: Recrawled this watch 11 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/react_frontend' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/react_frontend'`

warning: Watchman `query` returned a warning: Recrawled this watch 11 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/react_frontend' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/react_frontend'`

Recrawled this watch 11 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/react_frontend' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/react_frontend'`
```

How do I get my node console with the logs from the emulator back?